# Google Apps Script Close()

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to close a UI window that has opened in Apps Script?

I think the answer is no per: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=474&can=1&q=.close%28%29&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

but I wanted to see if there were other opinions.

I have a "Waiting window" that pops up, that I want to close when the activity is finished.

---

```
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = getSheetWithSubmissions(ss);

// create UI app, this works fine

app = createWaitPleaseUI(sheet);

ss.show(app);

//simulated activity

Utilities.sleep(5000);

//this doesn't work despite being in the documentation

app.close();
```

---

Think this is not possible but wish Google would dump it from their documentation if it can't be done.

As a workaround, I can bring up a second GUI saying "work complete, click OK" and then it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

You have to return the `app` object for any changes to be updated to it, even closing.

Change your last line to `return app.close()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should read the documentation more thoroughly, it is clearly explained that UI in spreadsheets need to be ended by a return to actually close.  Also I would suggest that you might trust the answer coming from a top contributor instead of believing that you are always right against the doc and everybody else ... no offence but a bit of humility is always welcome :-)

here is an piece of code extracted from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#DisplayingSpreadsheet) to corroborate :

```
// Close everything return when the close button is clicked
function close() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  // The following line is REQUIRED for the widget to actually close.
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Note that the issue you are referring to does not apply you your example:  it's about standalone UI, not UIs in spreadsheet .